# How to set attr parent() ::before element using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
if ($(input).attr('type') == 'email' || $(input).attr('name') == 'email') {
    if ($(input).val().trim().match(/^([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.)|(([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\.)+))([a-zA-Z]{1,5}|[0-9]{1,3})(\]?)$/) == null) {
        $(input).parent().css('content', "'Email không hợp lệ'");
        return false;
    }
}
```

How to change content this?

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour], have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Please post code, error messages, markup, and other textual information **as text**, not as a *picture* of text. Why: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/157247

Comment: Closely related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5041494/selecting-and-manipulating-css-pseudo-elements-such-as-before-and-after-usin (actually, it should be marked duplicate, silly of me to unmark it).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Selecting and manipulating CSS pseudo-elements such as ::before and ::after using javascript (or jQuery)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5041494/selecting-and-manipulating-css-pseudo-elements-such-as-before-and-after-usin)

Comment: Please show code text as text, not as pictures of text. See [ask], where it says "**DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc.** - copy or type the text into the question." (emphasis in the original).

Answer (score 0):

The `content: attr(data-validate)` CSS line means that the value of the element's `data-attribute` property should be used as the content of the pseudo-element (`::before`). In consequence, you need to alter the value of the attribute:

```
$(input).parent().attr('data-validate', "'Email không hợp lệ'");
```

Comment: @T.J.Crowder In the CSS for `::before` (which is one of the screenshots), it says `content: attr(data-validate);`.

Comment: @ZoliSzabó - Ah, okay, sorry. I can't read the image of text very well.

Comment: @haibq - Did you do **exactly** what's above? In particular, did you use `attr()` (**not** `data()`)?

Comment: It's worked, I was try without parent() :'(
But I want to know this problem